# Where to buy pin headers with non-standard pitch (1.5 mm)?

Tags: prototyping, pins, header

Recently I bought [this graphic LCD from Mouser](http://pt.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Newhaven-Display/NHD-C12832A1Z-FSW-FBW-3V3/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvkC18yXH9iIjqe6IqxYXYlWEPha/vwHCQ=) and I didn't noticed that the pin's pitch is not standard (2.54mm/0.1inch). It's 1.5mm. I don't want to solder this LCD directly on a PCB so I'm looking for a female pin header [like this](http://store.fundamentallogic.com/ecom/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=34), but didn't find any until now.

Do you know where can I buy pin headers with non-standard pitch?
I usually buy my electronic parts from Futurlec or Mouser. I have preference for Europe distributors but China or USA it's ok.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you might struggle to find one easily - I just had a quick look on a few sites and I couldn't come up with anything decent. 1.27mm is very common (being half of 2.54mm) but not 1.5mm, though there are quite a few crimp style plugs nothing with solder termination seemed to turn up.  
You might want to try asking Newhaven for alternative mounting recommendations, but if they are anything like DisplayTech be prepared to wait a while for a reply :-) Another option (if nothing turns up in the answers) might be to buy one of the cable headers and hack it.

Comment: Another option would be to consider making a simple single-layer PCB using laser-printer toner-transfer to adapt it to a more common connector pitch.  You can "surface mount" each set of pins at the edge of the board and thus avoid drilling any holes.

Comment: Have you taken a look at RS-Online? http://www.rs-online.com

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet with odd connectors like that is to check the catalogs of the big connector manufacturers directly for the part you need and try to find a vendor from there. I couldn't find anything at all from Molex (they had 1.5mm pitch, but only up to 12 positions). However, it looks like [Tyco Connectivity has something you can possibly use](http://www.te.com/catalog/bin/TE.Connect?C=12054&M=FEAT&P=175656,10008,2336,173449&U=&BML=10576,17560,23645,17579&LG=1).

Those are 1.5mm pitch, 17-position receptacles, but they're sized for 24-28 AWG wires so you'll want to double check the dimensions on the socket vs your LCD pins. If I'm reading their drawings correctly, the sockets are sized so that you can fit wires in them without stripping all of the insulation, so your 0.5 x 0.6 mm pins should be OK in terms of fitting in. What I would worry about is that the specced wire sans insulation is a bit smaller than your pins, which could cause problems with making a good connection. You'll probably just have to get one and test it out.